# Defining a recursive integral sequence

Tags: recursion, sequence

I have a recursive integral sequence as follows:
$$y_0(x)=1+r,$$
$$y_1(x)=-\frac{1}{\Gamma(a)}\int_0^x (x-t)^{a-1} y_0(t) dt,$$
$$\vdots$$
 $$y_n(x)=-\frac{1}{\Gamma(a)}\int_0^x (x-t)^{a-1} y_{n-1}(t) dt,\quad 0<a<1.$$
I wrote the following code but the output answer isn't correct. I know this problem is caused by the change of variables($t‎\leftrightarrow‎ x$ ) in $y_n(x)$. How to modify this problem?

```
Y[0, x_] = 1 + r;
Y[k_, x_] := 
 Y[k, x] =FullSimplify[-(1/Gamma[a])*Integrate[(x - t)^(a - 1)*(Y[k - 1, t]), {t, 0, x}]]
For[i = 0, i <= 10, i++, Print["Y", i, "[x]=", Simplify[Y[i, x]]]]
```

Comment: 1. $y_0(x)=1+r$ or $y_0(x)=1+x$? 2. Does $y_n(x)$ depend on $a$ or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Y[x_, n_] := Y[x, n] = -Simplify[
Integrate[(x - t)^(a - 1) (Y[x, n - 1] /. x -> t), {t, 0, x}, 
  Assumptions -> 0 < a < 1, GenerateConditions -> False]/Gamma[a]]
```

If we set `Y[x_, 0] = 1+r` then this yields the result $$y_n(x) = \frac{(-1)^n (1+r) x^{na}}{\Gamma(1+na)}.$$  Is this the answer you are looking for?  In the case where you intended $y_0(x) = 1 + x$ instead of $1+r$, the result would be $$y_n(x) = \frac{(-1)^n (1+na+x)x^{na}}{\Gamma(2+na)}.$$  You can also do the whole thing as a single `NestList` command:

```
NestList[-Simplify[
    Integrate[(x - t)^(a - 1) (# /. x -> t), {t, 0, x}, 
      Assumptions -> 0 < a < 1, GenerateConditions -> False]/
     Gamma[a]] &, 1 + r, 10]
```

Once we know the form of $y_n(x)$, we can just create an explicit definition so that it is not necessary to do the computation:

```
Y[x_, n_, a_, r_] := (-1)^n (1 + r) x^(n a)/Gamma[1 + n a]
```

Then to get a plot for $a = 1/2$, $r = 2$, $n = 1, 2, \ldots, 10$, we just do something like

```
Plot[Evaluate[Table[Y[x, n, 1/2, 2], {n, 1, 10}]], {x, 0, 3}]
```

Or if you want to be fancy and make an interactive plot,

```
Manipulate[Plot[Y[x, n, 1/2, 2], {x, 0, 3}, PlotRange -> {-6, 6}], {n, 1, 10, 1}]
```

And for a two-column set of formulas for $a = 1/2$,

```
TableForm[Table[TraditionalForm /@ {Y[x, n, a, r], Y[x, n, 1/2, r]}, {n, 1, 10}]]
```

If you want TeX output, instead use

```
TeXForm[Table[{Y[x, n, a, r], Y[x, n, 1/2, r]}, {n, 1, 10}]]
```

Comment: @herppup, Thanks, $Y[x_, 0] = 1+r$. How to plot all together in a coordinate axis  when $a=1/2, r=2$?

Comment: How to print Y[x, n,a] and Y[x, n,a=1/2] in two columns facing each other s.t n=1,...,10.

Comment: Excellent. Sorry, I wanna appear " $Y_n[x]=$ " in the Output.  TableForm[Table[TraditionalForm /@ {Print["Y", n, "[x]="]Y[x, n, a, r],Print["Y", n, "[x]="] Y[x, n, 1/2, r]}, {n, 1, 10}]]

Comment: This way of formatting may look nicer:  TableForm[Table[{TraditionalForm[Subscript[y, n][x] == Y[x, n, 1/2, r]]}, {n, 1, 10}]]